# keeping socket alive android for dummies

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask, client

I am writing my first Android app and I need to know how to start a socket as soon as my application is started and then keep the socket alive in order to send and receive some strings and use them in main activity.

I have tried AsyncTask, a Thread in an Application Class, and read of IntentServices but I couldn't get it done especially because I didn't know if its going to work at all.

Please tell me concretely which classes I need to use and where to define and initialize my socket.
(Or how to start a socket in UI Thread which is on default forbidden by Android System.)

Comment: In theory, any of the approaches you've mentioned could work, provided they're implemented correctly. Without any implementation details however, there's not much more we can tell you. We *can* tell you that performing any long-running operations on the UI thread is *always* a bad idea, regardless of whether the OS actually forbids it or not.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What kind of socket ? (tcp,udp, multicast?) 
What behavior are you experiencing that the socket is "not" alive.  Is it disconnecting?  time out?  any errors?  Please describe the current undesired behavior.